# Symfony 2: Override symfony component

Tags: php, symfony

I'm searching how to override a component of symfony. In my specific case I would like to override the MessageCatalogue class of the Translation component to be able to send event when no translations have been found. 
Is this even possible ?

Comment: Since Symfony 2.6 the Translation component comes with a [LoggingTranslator](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/LoggingTranslator.php). Isn't that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Here's a detailed guide on [how to override any part of a bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html). The first example shows what you are looking for.

```php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/OverrideServiceCompilerPass.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('original-service-id');
        $definition->setClass('Acme\DemoBundle\YourService');
    }
}
```

However, xabbuh's comment on your question seems to be an easier solution.

Comment: Swapping implementations by changing the class parameter should not be considered (for example, this will break when upgrading to Symfony 3.0 where all those parameters have been removed). A better approach is to use [service decoration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#decorating-services) instead (or replacing the class in a compiler pass as in your second example).

Comment: I amended my answer, xabbuh.